# Why no upvote on the question?

Tags: discussion

Since this site began, I've noticed that despite a question being decent enough to warrant an answer, the same user/s will not upvote the question?

Reputation points are valuable to old and especially new users, and engage them further making them want to return. If you're going to answer, then upvoting the question should be almost automatic!

Can people explain to me their reasoning behind not giving an upvote to a question, despite the fact that they took the time to craft an answer?

Comment: I think this can be seen on most if not all sites in the network. In fact, I'm guilty of it as well quite often...

Comment: Just because there is an answer does not mean it is a good question.  Lack of formatting or little effort.

Comment: @Paparazzi That's what the edit button is for ;) Be nice and vote it up after you have improved the formatting.

Comment: Or it could be a dupe. There are many questions on which hand wins, or how to deal with a split pot, yet rather than flag them as dupes, some users will post an answer anyway.